# Actualizar datos de un ListFragment con la información de un servicio que usa un AsyncTask para traer la información y mostrar la notificación

Tags: android, webservice, android-asynctask, arrayadapter

Buen día, estoy desarrollando una app que muestra notificaciones, entonces decidí utilizar un servicio para traer los datos del Webserver cuando la app no este corriendo, este servicio para traer la información antes usaba un hilo unido al hilo del UI, pero debido a que esto hacía que la app se congelara o se detuviera entonces decidí utiliazar un AsyncTask para traer la información en background, ahora el inconveniente es que no se como actulizar el adaptador del Listfragment que muestra la información que se trae del servidor y también mostrar esa información como notificación.

Service Class Notification and the query Asynctask:

```
    public class ServicioDB extends IntentService implements AsyncResponse{
// Variables de la notificacion
static String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager nm;
Notification notif;
private Conexion con=new Conexion();
private String data;
private ArrayList<Notificacion> notis = new ArrayList<>();
private DBDataConverter dbConverter=new DBDataConverter();
private ConsultarNoti asyncTask =new ConsultarNoti();

//Defino los iconos de la notificacion en la barra de notificacion
int icono_v = R.drawable.konradlogo;
int icono_r = R.drawable.konradlogo;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
public ServicioDB() {
    super("Hola Mundo");
}


@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    //this to set delegate/listener back to this class
    asyncTask.delegate=this;
    //execute the async task
     asyncTask.execute();




    if(data==null){}
    else {
        if (!(data.equalsIgnoreCase(""))) {
            for (int i = 0; i < notis.size(); i++) {
                // Inicio el servicio de notificaciones accediendo al servicio
                nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

                // Realizo una notificacion por medio de un metodo hecho por mi
                notificacion(icono_r, "NotifiK", notis.get(i).getHeader(), notis.get(i).getDescription());

                // Lanzo la notificacion creada en el paso anterior
                nm.notify(i + 1, notif);
            }

        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {    }


//this override the implemented method from asyncTask
@Override
public void processFinish(String output) {
    //Here you will receive the result fired from async class
    //of onPostExecute(result) method.
    data=output;
    notis = dbConverter.filtrarDatosNotificacion(data);
    DataSingleton.getInstance().setArrayNotificaciones(notis);
    NotificacionListFragment nl=new NotificacionListFragment();
    nl.loadNotificaciones();
    nl.onPause();
    nl.onResume();
    asyncTask.cancel(true);
}

//AsyncTask para insertar Personas
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
class ConsultarNoti extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

    private Activity context;
    private Conexion con= new Conexion();
    private String data;


    ConsultarNoti(){

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        data=con.conectLoadNoti();
        return data;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String datos) {
        delegate.processFinish(datos);

    }
}

public void notificacion(int icon, CharSequence textoEstado, CharSequence titulo, CharSequence texto) {
    // Capturo la hora del evento
    long hora = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Definimos la accion de la pulsacion sobre la notificacion (esto es opcional)
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ServicioDB.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    // Defino la notificacion, icono, texto y hora
    notif = new Notification(icon, textoEstado, hora);
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, titulo, texto, contentIntent);

    //Defino que la notificacion sea permamente
    //notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
}

}
```

NotificationListFragment

```
   public class NotificacionListFragment extends ListFragment {
private ArrayList<Notificacion> notificaciones;
private ArrayAdapter<Notificacion> adapter;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    ArrayAdapter<Notificacion> adapter = new NotificacionAdapter(getActivity(), notificaciones);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ((NotificacionAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    createNotificaciones();
    if(notificaciones==null){
        notificaciones = new ArrayList<Notificacion>();
        notificaciones.add(new Notificacion());
    }
    adapter = new NotificacionAdapter(getActivity(), notificaciones);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

   /* Notificacion pregunta = ((NotificacionAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);

    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PreguntaActivity.class);
    //posicion del clic
    i.putExtra("PreguntaIndex", position);
    startActivity(i);*/

}

private void createNotificaciones(){
    if (notificaciones == null)
        notificaciones = DataSingleton.getInstance().getArrayNotificaciones();
}

protected void loadNotificaciones(){
    if (notificaciones == null) {
        notificaciones = DataSingleton.getInstance().getArrayNotificaciones();
    }
}

}
```

¿Alguien me podría ayudar? o por lo menos explicarme si hay otro método para hacerlo, Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Viendo que nadie te ha respondido a ver si te soy de ayuda.

El listfragment tiene un método llamado `notifyDataSetChanged`

Pones el adapter de tu fragment como variable de clase, cosa que ya tienes, y tras traerte los datos haces un:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Obviamente asegúrate de haber rellenado el adapter con la nueva lista de objetos.

Creo que usas la lista llamada notificaciones, pues haz al terminar de traer los datos a esa lista hazte

```
    notificaciones.clear();
    notificaciones.addAll(nuevaListaDeNotificaciones);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    setListShown(true);//esto solo es necesario si no estas mostrando la lista.
```

Con la notificación no te puedo ayudar.

Comment: Gracias, pero no me funciono, dice que tanto el ArrayList como el adaptador son nulos